# broken image icon in django template

Tags: html, css, django, static

[image]My image and my background image will not load. I've tried many things and cant figure It out. I always get the broken image icon instead and the background wont load...

this is my settings

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
.
.
.
.
.
.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reviews/static')
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')

    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is my template called home.html

```
{% load static %}

<center>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</body>

<h2>WELCOME </h2>

<img src="{% static 'logo.jpeg' %}" >

<a href="http://localhost:8000/shop">SHOP</a>

<a href="http://localhost:8000/reviews/">REVIEW</a> 





<div id="overlay"></div>


<title>yorleì</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
  background-image: url('/static/reviews/Background.jpeg');
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-black">
  <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding-large w3-xlarge">

  </div>
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-animate-top">COMING SOON</h1>
    <hr class="w3-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:40%">
    <p class="w3-large w3-center">35 days left</p>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and i always get a broken image! HELP ME PLEASE!
Also the file isn't connecting to the css file i names home.css

what am i doing wrong?!

Comment: Also the file is saved into a folder called static

Comment: Show us your entire folders structure

Comment: I uploaded a photo

Comment: What's your `settings.STATIC_URL` and `settings.STATIC_ROOT`.
Also how are your running your server?
Are you using `python manage.py runserver` in dev or are you running it in production?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1) CSS File not working.

Try this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'reviews/home.css' %}">`

I would also recommend creating a css folder to properly seperate your files, the same with js if you plan to add any JavsScript files. For example, reviews/css/home.css and reviews/js/home.js.

Problem 2) Background image not working.

Try this: `background-image: url("{% static 'reviews/Background.jpeg' %}");`

If your image doesn't show up (like mine did when I just tested this), then make sure you're not putting a white image against a white background haha! Also for common practice you don't want two body tags in your html file. You should also move the title, meta and link tags into the head.

Hope this helps! Let me know if this does or doesn't work.